# Removing styling from ag-grid output after render

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid, vuejs2

I'm working on a styling change of an ag-grid output to push the rows apart with a bit of margin space between each row.

Using a `decendant selector` in CSS3 appears to work fine to over-ride the .ag-row class, but somewhere along the line during render ag-grid adds a `top` property *inline* to the row style based on the height of the rows.

The result is that although I have a rule that says the rows have a 30px margin added to the bottom of each row it's being over-ridden by the top rules, putting the following rows right underneath each other, as in a default grid layout.

I've read up on ag-grids' `getRowStyle()` and `processRowPostCreate()` built-in functions, but I understand this is for adding or modifying styles, not removing styles.  At least I do not find any examples that might give me a hint on removing that annoying top rule.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated!  See attached screenshots of the rendered ag-grid HTML to see the top rule in action on the right panel of the Chrome developer tools.  In the first screen shot, you can see that the webdev tools are showing the margin space in the left panel, so the rule is getting used.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it'd be easier to set the row height 30px larger?

Comment: try to override while returning style in getRowStyle : setRowColors.   function setRowColors(params){return {'margin-bottom':'30px'};}

Comment: @AnthonyC I was under the impression that row height is what the top rule uses to compute the next row position - to put it right under the previous row ala table-style.  So increasing row height would just change the top position... or not?

Comment: @Basavaraj I'll give that a try, but doesn't make too much sense as it does not address the re-computed top position based on row height.  But strangers things have happened!  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @thedigitalmouse, I thought you wanted to make the row to be 30 px longer by adding margin-bottom: 30px, is that not the case?

Comment: no, no. I was trying to use margin-bottom to push the rows apart from each other.  but the inline addition of `top` seems to override that during render.